# transpose with multiple variables in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS, I have column variables in sequence with corresponding column variables stacked side by side, such as the following:

```
 id lab1 lab2 lab3 dt1  dt2  dt3  bili1 bili2 bili3 alb1 alb2 alb3
 3  dx   sx   sx   2/04 2/06 3/08 x.x   x.x   x.x   x.x  x.x  x.x 
 4  dx   tx   tx   5/05 3/06 9/06 x.x   x.x   x.x   x.x  x.x  x.x
```

and I want to transpose to the following long format:

```
 id lab dt   bili alb
 3  dx  2/04 x.x  x.x
 3  sx  2/06 x.x  x.x
 3  sx  3/08 x.x  x.x
 4  dx  5/05 x.x  x.x
 4  tx  3/06 x.x  x.x
 4  tx  9/06 x.x  x.x
```

but I can't seem to manipulate this correctly, by putting

```
var lab1-lab3 dt1-dt3 bili1-bili3 alb1-alb3;
```

there's actually no difference between that and

```
var lab1-alb3
```

so each column is treated independently, but I'd like to cluster these so SAS knows they have individual columns in the long dataset. Some forums have advised me to just perform the transpose several times and merge the output data. This seems inelegant, inefficient, hard to read, and tedious... more so than SAS is on its own. Is there no syntax to perform this in a single data or proc step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not going to get there with PROC TRANSPOSE without a lot of extra work.  Most of the time, Wide to Long is easier handled within the data step.  In this case you can do it very easily with arrays.

```
data have;
input id lab1 $ lab2 $ lab3 $ dt1 $ dt2 $ dt3 $ 
      bili1 $ bili2 $ bili3 $ alb1 $ alb2 $ alb3 $;
datalines;
 3  dx   sx   sx   2/04 2/06 3/08 x.x   x.x   x.x   x.x  x.x  x.x 
 4  dx   tx   tx   5/05 3/06 9/06 x.x   x.x   x.x   x.x  x.x  x.x 
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
array labs lab1-lab3;
array dts dt1-dt3;
array bilis bili1-bili3;
array albs alb1-alb3;

do _t = 1 to dim(labs);
  lab = labs[_t];
  dt  = dts[_t];
  bili= bilis[_t];
  alb = albs[_t];
  output;
end;
keep id lab dt bili alb;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single data step, wrapped in a macro, like this:

```
%macro trans;

data want(keep = id lab dt bili alb);
set have;
%do i = 1 %to 3;
    lab = lab&i;
    dt = dt&i;
    bili = bili&i;
    alb = alb&i;
    output;
%end;
run;

%mend;

%trans; run;
```

Comment: Why use macros when you can use arrays?  You're just introducing an extra step of complexity that is unneeded.

Comment: At first glance it seemed easier to modify if 3 is not the real number of variables here, but only used to illustrate the issue, and it's less code.

Comment: Inserting a macro where you don't have any need or real benefit from one is just adding needless complexity to the code.  You could easily add a macro parameter (`%let numvars=3;`), or even just use : wildcard (`array labs lab:;`) if you are likely to need to modify that field.  In general, I don't think it's a good idea to write a whole data step macro for this sort of thing, even if you didn't like the array solution; write a macro for just the inner part, and call that inside the datastep.  IE, %trans(vars=%str(lab dt bili alb), num=3); .

Comment: This pattern actually comes up quite often in my code, thanks for the tip.